# Is there something in this code that defies syntax?

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io, while-loop, java.util.scanner

The question gives 6 integers in a file, separated into lines:

```
5
2
3
1
3
2
```

The 1st line describes the total number of days, and the others describe the number of hours per day. I am supposed to print the total number of days and the average number of hours. Here is my code below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IFeelFine 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File("Tax.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        double count = in.nextInt();
        double total = 0;
        for (double i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            total += in.nextDouble();
        }
        double avg = total / count;
        System.out.println("Total vacation time missed: " + total + " hours");
        System.out.println("Average daily time missed: " + avg + " hours");
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message in Eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at IFeelFine.main(IFeelFine.java:15)
```

What does that mean, and what do I have to fix to let the program run?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the OP doesn't need that. He is already doing "nextDouble()" which automatically goes to the next double.

Comment: @TheProgrammerG Ahhh. I see it now.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Read in the first one, add it to total; read in the second one, add it to avgTotal; read in the THIRD one, add it to total, etc. It's a clever trick to save time from doing the odd and even calculation.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Yeah :)

Comment: Well turns out I did the question wrong in the first place o_o Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your solution

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IFeelFine 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File("Tax.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        double total = 0;
        double avgTotal = 0;
        double counter = 0;
        int line = 0;
        while (in.hasNext())
        {
          if(line%2==0)
          {
            total += in.nextDouble();
          }
          else
          {
            avgTotal += in.nextDouble();
            counter ++;
          }
            line++;
            }
        double avg = avgTotal / counter;
        System.out.println("Total vacation time missed: " + total + " hours");
        System.out.println("Average daily time missed: " + avg + " hours");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do that. Read my comment in the question to see why.

Comment: @TheProgrammerG In OP's example, you may not need to do this. But what if there were an odd number of lines? In such a case, this answer would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Aurora_Titanium Only suggestion I might make is remove the `else if` redundancy. If `line%2==0` evaluates false, then `line%2!=0` will naturally evaluate true, so you really just need `else{}`

Answer (score -2):

Your answer works just fine. Here is the testing result:

```
Total vacation time missed: 11.0 hours
Average daily time missed: 1.6666666666666667 hours
```

This is correct according to your rule to calculate these values.

Comment: I'm using eclipse and it returns an error for some reason.